# How to check if a variable has been assigned a variable in AutoHotKey?

Tags: variables, try-catch, autohotkey, ahk2

How might one check if a variable exists before using it? For example, you might have an Object that can contains 36 keys, one for each alphanumeric character, and you want to set another variable to the value of the key you selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code could look like this:

```
myObject := {} ; Create myObject

; Some other code here, possibly that adds key-value pairs to the Object

getInput := InputHook("L1") ; Create an InputHook to intercept one character
getInput.Start() ; Start the InputHook
getInput.Wait() ; Wait for a character input

myVar := myObject.%getInput.Input% ; Set myVar to the pressed key in myObject
```

This code would work, unless the key that was entered doesn't exist, in which case an error will be thrown.
In order to avoid that situation, we can add turn `myVar := myObject.%getInput.Input%` into a `Try` statement. Now, our code will look like this:

```
myObject := {} ; Create myObject

; Some other code here, possibly that adds key-value pairs to the Object

getInput := InputHook("L1") ; Create an InputHook to intercept one character
getInput.Start() ; Start the InputHook
getInput.Wait() ; Wait for a character input

Try myVar := myObject.%getInput.Input% ; Set myVar to the pressed key in myObject
Catch
    myVar := "" ; If pressed key in myObject doesn't exist, set myVar to empty value
```

Now, if the pressed key is not a key existing in `myObject`, then `myVar` will be set to an empty value. The `catch` statement is not required, but including it means that any future operations on `myVar` will have a value to operate on.

You can find more information on `Try-Catch` statements on the [AutoHotkey Docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Try.htm).

Comment: Speaking in terms of good code practises, try-catch shouldn't be used for logic. You should use [`HasOwnProp()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Object.htm#HasOwnProp) for this: `myVar := myObject.HasOwnProp(getInput.Input) ? myObject.%getInput.Input% : ""`.

Comment: @0x464e Yeah, that would work a lot better. The reason I used try-catch is because there is no function to detect if a variable exists, so it has to try an operation on it and do something else if an error is thrown.